# No resizing, but positioning when setting backgroundImage of UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage

I want the button to basically overlap a certain part of the original picture and crop the rest instead of squishing the picture into the button. I can't seem to find a UIContentMode to achieve this.

[image: uibutton]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

You can have a UIImage after some CGRect inside any UIViews. Just make a CGRect with the part of the UIImageView that contains your original UIImage, and execute the code below:

```
 CGRect newImageFrame = CGRectMake(...); //fill this rect according to the crop area of the imageView
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageFrame, YES, 0);
 [editingCell.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
 UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Now the `newImage` will hold the image that you will use as background of your button.

Example:
Assuming your UIImageView has the frame (50,50, 100, 200), you can crop a similar result of your image with something like this: newImageFrame = CGRectMake(50, 130, 100, 40).

Please, let me know if worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

please try this code:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, y, 280, 40);
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = frame;
        button.tag=i;
        [button setTitle:(NSString *)@"new button" forState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"temp.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:button];
```

i have checked it out.

hope this will help you.